# Macro to delete rows freezes half the time

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a more efficient way to do the below operation of adding three cell values in  a row to the corresponding cells above and then deleting the old row? Half the time the macro freezes; I am running it on about 12,000 lines (there are no dynamic formulas on the sheet).

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For a = Lcell To 2 Step -1
   If Cells(a, 23).Value = Cells(a - 1, 23).Value Then
       Cells(a, 16).Value = Cells(a, 16).Value + Cells(a - 1, 16).Value
       Cells(a, 17).Value = Cells(a, 17).Value + Cells(a - 1, 17).Value
       Cells(a, 18).Value = Cells(a, 18).Value + Cells(a - 1, 18).Value
       Cells(a - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
   End If
Next a

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: your starting at the bottom and working up but then your deleting the row above? how would that work?!

Comment: never use `application.screenupdating = false` until your code is working properly. I'm pretty sure that you'll see the issue if you comment that out.

Comment: Have you commented `application.screeunpdating` and stepped through the code in the debugger to see if you can identify where/why it's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Steve Martin's suggestion, try this:

```
For a = Lcell To 2 Step -1
   If Cells(a, 23).Value = Cells(a - 1, 23).Value Then
       Cells(a-1, 16).Value = Cells(a, 16).Value + Cells(a - 1, 16).Value
       Cells(a-1, 17).Value = Cells(a, 17).Value + Cells(a - 1, 17).Value
       Cells(a-1, 18).Value = Cells(a, 18).Value + Cells(a - 1, 18).Value
       Cells(a, 1).EntireRow.Delete
   End If
Next a
```

Answer (score 0):

One option when deleting cells is to use the UNION-DELETE pattern.  This saves the deletion step until after the logic is determined and does it all at once.  This technique allows deleting a Range that is being iterated through.  It also reduces operations which should improve increase speed.  I have not tested it for speed though.

**Edited code to delete last row based on comments**

```
Dim rng_delete As Range

For A = Lcell To 2 Step -1
   If Cells(A, 23).Value = Cells(A - 1, 23).Value Then
       Cells(A - 1, 16).Value = Cells(A, 16).Value + Cells(A - 1, 16).Value
       Cells(A - 1, 17).Value = Cells(A, 17).Value + Cells(A - 1, 17).Value
       Cells(A - 1, 18).Value = Cells(A, 18).Value + Cells(A - 1, 18).Value

        'rng_delete starts empty which errors Union on first add
        If rng_delete Is Nothing Then
            Set rng_delete = Cells(A, 1).EntireRow
        Else
            Set rng_delete = Union(rng_delete, Cells(A, 1).EntireRow)
        End If
   End If
Next A

rng_delete.Delete
```

Comment: Good idea Byron, I thought of this as well but you need to delete the rows while you loop through the lines otherwise it will not consolidate all the values in cell(a, 23), there will be duplicates.

Comment: @user3822304, ahh, I see it now.  You are deleting the row above the last one.  Missed the `A-1` there.  Can you delete the last row instead and work your way up, or is there something special about the 2nd to last row?  In my code that would be: `Cells(A, 1).EntireRow` instead of the `A-1`.  And the formulas above would set `Cells(A-1,16) = ...` instead of `Cells(A,...)`.

Comment: I was too quick to confirm error resolution; I still get the same issue as above. The debugger is saying the rng_delete.Delete line is the issues. Any guesses?

Comment: Hard to say without more info about the specifics of the spreadsheet when it errors.  Using `Union` makes it a little harder to debug also since it can be a large range that it is trying to delete.  You can try and delete rows as you go again and see if a specific row is causing the error.  You can also do `rng_delete.Select` instead of deleting to see what it wants to delete.  Or `Debug.Print rng_delete.Address` if the `Select` fails.